# Python - How to run a cronjob daily night 2 am

Tags: cron, cron-task

I am running cron Job, for daily night 2 am. I am using

```
00 2 * * * sudo python /var/www/html/ga/myfile.py
```

But I getting

```
00: command not found
```

In my server crontab is installed already. If I do -

```
sudo crontab -l
```

I am getting also respective response. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Though to ask here, as a best platform

Comment: You should try to run 00 2 * * * /var/www/html/ga/myfile.py, let me know the output.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Gottacha. @NabeelShaikh